# For every record table take the latest value from another, how to run faster

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL:

```
        SELECT stage.s_f4101.country, stage.s_f4101.itm, stage.s_f4101.litm, 
stage.s_f4101.aitm, stage.s_f4101.descr, stage.s_f4101.descr_en, 
stage.s_f4101.glpt, stage.s_f4101.barcode, stage.s_f4101.lnty, 
stage.s_f4101.stkt, stage.s_f4101.uom1, stage.s_f4101.uom2, stage.s_f4101.ptsc, 
stage.s_f4101.prp1, stage.s_f4101.prp2, stage.s_f4101.prp3, stage.s_f4101.prp4, 
stage.s_f4101.prp5, stage.s_f4101.prp6, stage.s_f4101.prp7, stage.s_f4101.prp8, 
stage.s_f4101.prp9, stage.s_f4101.prp0, stage.s_f4101.isblk, 
stage.s_f4101.design_id,
      (SELECT top 1 wa
       FROM stage.s_f74g4105 dd
       WHERE dd.mslitm = stage.s_f4101.litm
         AND dd.country=stage.s_f4101.country
       ORDER BY msfyr DESC, mscmon DESC) wa_latest
    FROM stage.s_f4101
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_41p4 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_41p4.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.prp4 = stage.s_udc_41p4.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_4103 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_4103.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.prp8 = stage.s_udc_4103.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_41p5 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_41p5.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.prp5 = stage.s_udc_41p5.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_4107 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_4107.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.srp7 = stage.s_udc_4107.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_4105 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_4105.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.prp0 = stage.s_udc_4105.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_41p1 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_41p1.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.prp1 = stage.s_udc_41p1.udckey
    LEFT OUTER JOIN stage.s_udc_41s5 ON stage.s_f4101.country = stage.s_udc_41s5.country
    AND stage.s_f4101.srp5 = stage.s_udc_41s5.udckey
```

Basically my problem is that it is getting slow because of the subquery that gets the field WA_LATEST.

What can i do to make it faster?

I have added the relative index that advisor suggests on S_F74G4105

Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_S_F74G4105_19_1733307122__K6_K1_K7_K8_12] ON [stage].[S_F74G4105]
(
    [MSLITM] ASC,
    [Country] ASC,
    [MSFYR] ASC,
    [MSCMON] ASC
)
```

Comment: Which indexes set up on the table `s_f74g4105 `?

Comment: Formatting your code to actually be readable within the supplied code window would do wonders to get me to actually be interested in your problem.

Comment: Hopefully formatted it a little bit better and added the index spec

Comment: Make two indexes `MSLITM, Country` and `MSFYR, MSCMON`.

Comment: Note sure if this will help but you might try specifying `DESC` for the MSFYR and MSCMON columns.

Comment: i will try the proposals..i was wondering if there is anythign i can do with the actual query.

Comment: NO change in speed with the 2 separate indexes nor with the DESC in the existing

Comment: Then you should analyse the execution plan to be able to make right decisions related to the query tuning.

Comment: Your question could be improved by removing unrelated joins and giving your tables better names than "S_F74G4105"  :)

Comment: It's good to try and improve your question, but stripping out the entire query goes a bit too far :) Rolled back your edit, hope that's ok

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a subquery with `row_number()` to retrieve all the "latest" in one go:

```
select   s_f4101.country
... 
,        latest.wa
FROM     s_f4101   
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by country, mslitm 
                    order by msfyr desc, mscmon desc) as rn
        ,       country
        ,       mslitm
        ,       wa
        from    s_f74g4105
        ) latest
ON      latest.rn = 1 -- Top row ordered by msfyr desc, mscmon desc
        and latest.country = s_f4101.country
        and latest.mslitm = s_f4101.litm
...
```

Comment: correct parition with partition..After that he complained about country and mslitm fields in latest..I added them after wa and tested, and it took ages again

Comment: Did you remove the `top 1 wa` query after you added this?  How long does it take if you run the `row_number()` query by itself?

Comment: if i want him to use my existing index i should change the order in partition to be mslitm,country..Will this hurt?

Comment: The column order in a `partition by` shouldn't matter, so you can change it all you like. Is the subquery with `row_number()` faster than the `top` query?

Comment: I think it is not faster

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a key lookup for s_f74g4105.wa each time when fetching the wa_latest. Does it help if you add wa as include column in the index? Looking at statistics io & query plan might help, but don't get fooled by the percentages in the plan, it's just estimates.

Comment: my bad, wa is in the index include, i didnt include it in my question. sorry